# My Shiny App remove the content of my Markdown when i call it and does not save as pdf

Tags: r, shiny, download, markdown, shinyapps

I am try to create a shiny app that calls a Markdown to download a PDF with a text entry that content a financial ticker stock

But when i press download button the markdown content is delete

Also when I click generate report it opens a file explorer and asks me to save a file called report but nothing is generated. In the console I get the following message:

Output created: Reporte_consulta_tu_accion_andes.pdf

This is my Shiny code:

```
 library(shiny) 
  library(quantmod)
  library(xts)
  library(formattable)
  library(TTR)
  library(stringi)
  library(docxtractr)
  library(shinyWidgets)
  library(shinythemes)
  library(tidyverse)
  library(tidyquant)
  library(plotly)
  library(ggplot2)
  library(knitr)
  shinyApp(
      ui = fluidPage(
          textInput("text","generar"),
          downloadButton("report", "Generate report"),
          textOutput("a")
          
          
      ),
      server = function(input, output) {
          
        #setwd("C:/Users/SAMUELYAICEL/Desktop/Escritorio/Blog_data_info/blog_data_info")
          output$report <- downloadHandler(
              # For PDF output, change this to "report.pdf"
              filename = "Reporte_consulta_tu_accion_andes.pdf",
              content = function(file) {
                  # Copy the report file to a temporary directory before processing it, in
                  # case we don't have write permissions to the current working dir (which
                  # can happen when deployed).
                  wd <- getwd()
                  tempReport <- file.path(wd, "Reporte_consulta_tu_accion_andes.rmd")
                
                  file.copy("Reporte_consulta_tu_accion_andes.pdf", 
                            tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
                  
                  # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
                  params <- list(text = input$text)
                  output$a <- reactive(input$text)
                  # Knit the document, passing in the `params` list, and eval it in a
                  # child of the global environment (this isolates the code in the document
                  # from the code in this app).
                  rmarkdown::render(tempReport, 
                                    output_file = file,
                                    output_format = pdf(),
                                    params = params,
                                    envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
                  )
              }
          )
      }
  )
  
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And my Rmd file:

````
---
output: pdf_document
fontsize: 11pt
geometry: margin=2cm
number_sections: true
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  - \usepackage{lipsum}
  - \pagestyle{fancy}
  - \fancyhead[RO,LE]{Andes }
  - \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{@Andes}
params:
  text: NA
---

```{r, include=FALSE}
options(tinytex.verbose = TRUE)
```

```{r}
params[["text"]]
```

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(quantmod)
library(xts)
library(formattable)
library(TTR)
library(stringi)
library(docxtractr)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinythemes)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyquant)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(knitr)
ticker <- params[["text"]]
prices3 <- getSymbols(params[["text"]])
prices3
what_metrics <- yahooQF(c("Name",
                          "Symbol",
                          "Market Capitalization",
                          "P/E ratio",
                          "Dividend Yield",
                          #"Percent Change From 20-day Moving Average",
                          "Percent Change From 50-day Moving Average",
                          "Percent Change From 200-day Moving Average"))
Compania  <- getQuote(prices3, what=what_metrics)
```
````

I am a beginner, could someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: So you get a blank pdf as output? What do you want to print in it? Add `Compania` in the next line after `Compania  <- getQuote(prices3, what=what_metrics)` and try?

Comment: I try to print the variable "prices3" after using the quantmod package, but the PDF does not return anything, I do not know if I am sending the parameter to shiny wrong